# How to select from a table with additional where clause on a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum

I'm having trouble formulating a SQL query in Oracle. Here's my sample table:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id | start     | end       | number |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 1  | 21-dec-19 | 03-jan-20 | 12     |
| 2  | 23-dec-19 | 05-jan-20 | 10     |
| 3  | 02-jan-20 | 15-jan-20 | 9      |
| 4  | 09-jan-20 | NULL      | 11     |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

And here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    SUM(number) AS total_number,
    SUM(number) AS total_ended_number -- (WHERE end IS NOT NULL)
FROM table
WHERE ... -- a lot of where clauses
```

And the desired result:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| total_number | total_ended_number |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 42           | 31                 |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

I understand I could do a separate select inside 'total_ended_number', but the initial select has a bunch of where clauses already which would need to be applied to the internal select as well.

I'm capable of formulating it in 2 separate selects or 2 nested selects with all the where clauses duplicated, but my intended goal is to not duplicate the where clauses that would both be used on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `sum` over a `case` expression with this logic:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(number) AS total_number,
    SUM(CASE WHEN end IS NOT NULL THEN number END) AS total_ended_number
FROM table
WHERE ... -- a lot of where clauses
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM(case when "end" is not null then number else 0 end) AS total_ended_number
```